# How to edit page content after downloading the site files

Tags: ftp

I am new to WordPress and I've built a simple site. After that, I downloaded all the files of my site by Filezilla. May I ask how to change page content? Which folder is the page contents being stored?

Comment: The content is in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean "page content" as is content of your posts or markup of the web page?

### Content content

WordPress content is stored in MySQL database. To completely copy a site to your local computer you would need not only copy of files files, but:

1. Web server with PHP support to run it
2. MySQL server to import copy of database into

Running a local copy is staple practice for developers, but it's not too friendly for novices. There might be a better way, depending on *why* do you want to make changes outside of the site.

### Page source content

When WordPress produces markup for a site's front-end part it is using an active theme to do so. Theme files are stored in theme directory, typical case would be `wp-content/themes/[name]`.

However much of the WP popularity is due to how themes can use it's API to produce a lot of complex output, in relatively little theme code. So while theme might be *initiating* specific output, it might actually be *produced* by WP core functions.

The customization of that is really case by case.